# OpenJDK 17 Alpine build availability

Tags: java, alpine-linux, openjdk-17

It looks like https://jdk.java.net/17/ says alpine build is not available, but the alpine repo has a package. https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/openjdk17-jre

Any idea why this happens? Does this means alpine uses an early access build? not GA? How can we confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first page you linked *explains* why the Alpine build has been removed:

> "*The Alpine Linux build previously available on this page was removed as of the first JDK 17 release candidate. It is not production-ready because it has not been tested thoroughly enough to be considered a GA build. Please use the early-access JDK 18 Alpine Linux build in its place."*

> Does this means alpine uses an early access build?

I doubt it.

> Not GA?

Well, the GA builds were deemed to be not "GA quality" ... due to lack of testing.

But if you compare the build name (e.g. 17.0.2_p8-r1) with the tags in the OpenJDK repo ([here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u/tags)), it looks like the Alpine builds are tracking the 17u updates.  Indeed, it looks they are what the GA builds *would have been* ... if the team had been willing to apply the "GA" label to them.

This is moot if you follow the recommendation of the OpenJDK site and use the early-access JDK 18 Alpine Linux build instead.  Presumably they recommend this because they think it is *better quality* ... despite being early access!

> How can we confirm this?

You could contact the person responsible for creating the Alpine builds.  Or you could look at the evidence yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen C.
I will have a word with one of the alpine developers to see if we can consider this as a production ready package. But thanks for looking into and giving some more insights around the tracking repo. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## Search JDK

You just need to search either openjdk or specific openjdk17

```bash
apk search openjdk
```

> **Or**

```bash
apk search openjdk17
```

> **Then just install after checking your favorite on the list, which on our case is openjdk17.**

```bash
apk add openjdk17
```

#### Hope it helps!

---

## Configure to work on terminal

> Ensure nano is installed through `apk add nano` then open bash source file but for this case we will use zsh.

```bash
nano  ~/.zshrc
```

> Paste the following on the end of file.

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/server
```

> Restart zsh to save the changes. Thats all, next run java files on Alpine wsl.

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```